# Facebook apprequests opened in Android doesn't open Google Market or app

Tags: android, facebook, facebook-graph-api, facebook-javascript-sdk

I expose my problem, I have a Canvas App (just with an image and two links to download the app both for iOS and Android), up to this point, is ok, first time you run this Canvas App will ask for you for basic permission.

Now I want to build an app in my localhost which will invite my friend to use my app, to do so, I login in my app in order to send the request to use my app. This point is ok, since I configured the field **"Website with Facebook login"** with my localhost and not the Canvas page. And the apprequest my friends open in Facebook website on a PC works fine.

My problem appears in Android, since when my friends open the apprequest it redirects them to open a browser in the smartphone, and the url loaded is my localhost followed by request_ids, etc. (something like this: localhost:5000/?request_ids= 15613546846...), it does so instead of opening google market or an installed app in my smartphone, but it doesn't open the app even being installed, after clicking the apprequest. (In the image below doesn't appear the configuration to a Native Android App but is configured).

Maybe is bad configured or it doesn't recognize the app, could someone provide me an android app sample to be opened after clicking and apprequest in Android Facebook?

I must say that in iOS Native App, just writing the iphone store id work properly. Opening it the app store to download the app.

My app configuration is:

(myapp.herokuapp.com is a fake address, but actually I'm using heroku).

[image]

Comment: If anyone has any tip for this I would really apreciate it.

Comment: Did you ever find out why this did not work? I have the same issue. I use the invite in 2 different apps, in one app it is working, the other one is redirecting to my website instead of the playstore. I am using the exact same code for both apps.